# Fixed header and footer with variable height two-module sidebar

Tags: css, position, html, css-position

I have a layout with a fixed footer and header, and what I want is for the "info-box" div to be variable height, and have "scrolling-div" fill the remaining vertical height in the right column.  As you can see from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYzJL/), if I set height of scrolling-div to 100%, it becomes as tall as the right column, not the remaining space.

This is the HTML for the page:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="main-container">
        <div id="page-content">
        <div id="left-column">
        </div>
        <div id="right-column">
            <div id="info-box">
            This is a variable height div</div>
            <div id="scrolling-div">
                Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br /> Loads and loads of scrolling content<br /><br />

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the CSS:

```
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#header {
    position:fixed;
    height:45px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    top:0;
}

#footer {
    position:fixed;
    height:45px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    bottom:0
}

#main-container {
    background:#00FF00;
    position:absolute;
    top:45px;
    bottom:45px;
    width:100%
}

#page-content {
    width:960px;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#FFF000;
    height:100%;
}

#left-column {
    background-color:#444444;
    width:400px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}

#right-column {
    background-color:#0000FF;
    float:right;
    width:560px;
    z-index:10000;
    height:100%;
}

#info-box {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#0F0F0F;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#scrolling-div {
   background-color:#FFFFFF;
    height:200px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

And again, a [link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYzJL/) to see it in action.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to rely on some JS trickery to do this - I was thinking of using `calc()` in CSS, but realized that the `#info-box` will be of variable height. You can use a simple line of jQuery to set the height of `#scrolling-div` to be the height of its parent container minus the height of its sibling:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#scrolling-div").height($("#right-column").height()-$("#info-box").height());
});
```

If you want to future-proof this set up (like, if you have more than one sibling in the container), you can use the following function instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Define some variables
    var $sdiv = $("#scrolling-div"),
        sibHeight = 0;

    // Get sum of siblings height
    $sdiv.siblings().each(function() {
       sibHeight += $(this).height(); 
    });

    // Set own height to parent's height - sum of siblings height
    $sdiv.height($sdiv.parent().height()-sibHeight);
});
```

And instead of using `overflow: scroll`, I recommend using `overflow-y: auto` instead ;)

See the edited fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/2qXZG/

Comment: Thanks!  I should have said I have done it already with jQuery--but I was really hoping to accomplish it with CSS :(.